# how to make the last div column stay on the top of the page in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I divided my divs into 4 columns, in the first column there is a previous page button arrow, in second and third columns contain the content and the last column contains the next page button arrow. But in the mobile view the last column arrow is at the bottom of the page, i need it to be placed on the top near to the previous button arrow.

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <form>
                            <input type="button" class="default_previous sprite" alt="Submit">
                        </form>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="container-two-grid">

                            <div class="grid-two imageandtext">
                                <figure>
                                   <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
                                   <label for="selimg1">
                                    <img src="assets/images/painting.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                                    </label>
                                     <input type="radio" name="selimg" id="selimg1">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <p>Painting</p>
                                    </div> 
                                    </div>                    
                                    <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
                                    <label for="selimg2">
                                        <img src="assets/images/photography.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" >
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="selimg" id="selimg2">
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <p>Photography</p>
                                        </div></div>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>

                                <div class="grid-two imageandtext">
                                <figure>
                                   <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
                                   <label for="selimg3">
                                    <img src="assets/images/drawing.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                                    </label>
                                     <input type="radio" name="selimg" id="selimg3">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <p>Drawing</p>
                                    </div> 
                                    </div>                    
                                    <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
                                    <label for="selimg4">
                                        <img src="assets/images/sculpture.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" >
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="selimg" id="selimg4">
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <p>Sculpture</p>
                                        </div></div>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>

                                <div class="grid-two imageandtext">
                                <figure>
                                   <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
                                   <label for="selimg5">
                                    <img src="assets/images/painting.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                                    </label>
                                     <input type="radio" name="selimg" id="selimg5">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <p>Painting</p>
                                    </div> 
                                    </div>                    
                                    <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
                                    <label for="selimg6">
                                        <img src="assets/images/photography.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" >
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="selimg" id="selimg6">
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <p>Photography</p>
                                        </div></div>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                               <div class="grid-two imageandtext">
                                <figure>
                                   <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
                                   <label for="selimg7">
                                    <img src="assets/images/drawing.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                                    </label>
                                     <input type="radio" name="selimg" id="selimg7">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <p>Drawing</p>
                                    </div> 
                                    </div>                    
                                    <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
                                    <label for="selimg8">
                                        <img src="assets/images/sculpture.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" >
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="selimg" id="selimg8">
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <p>Sculpture</p>
                                        </div></div>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>

                            </div>      


                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="container-form-grid">
                                <div class="subject_art">
                                    <form>
                                        <select class="mdb-select">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>Subject of ART</option>
                                            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                                            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </form>
                                </div>

                                <form class="form-inline">

                                    <h4>Dimensions</h4>
                                    <select class="mdb-select">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Units</option>
                                        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                                        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                                        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                                    </select>

                                </form>
                                <form class="form-inline">

                                    <div class="md-form form-group">

                                        <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
                                        <label for="form1" class="">Width</label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="md-form form-group">
                                        <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
                                        <label for="form1" class="">Height</label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="md-form form-group">
                                        <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
                                        <label for="form1" class="">Depth</label>
                                    </div>


                                </form>
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form_weight">
                                        <div class="md-form">
                                            <input type="text" id="form41" class="form-control">
                                            <label for="form41" class="">Weight</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                                <form class="form-inline">
                                <h4>ART Specifics</h4>
                                    <div class="form_row">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <select class="mdb-select">
                                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Medium</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                                                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <select class="mdb-select">
                                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Material</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                                                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><select class="mdb-select">
                                                <option value="" disabled selected>Styles</option>
                                                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                                                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                                                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                                            </select></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>





                                </form>
                                <form>
                                    <div class="md-form form-width">
                                        <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
                                        <label for="form1" class="">Keywords/Tags (Type 5 to 20 items)  </label>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <form>
                                <input type="button" class="default-next sprite" alt="Submit">

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

css(previous button and next button)

```
.uploadart_content .default-next{
      width: 83px;
      height: 65px;
      margin-right: 8px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      background-position: -71px -235px;
      margin-top: 341px;
      border:none;
      outline: none;

    }
    .uploadart_content .default_previous{
      width: 83px;
      height: 65px;
      margin-right: 8px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      background-position: -139px -235px;
      margin-top: 341px;
      border:none;
      outline: none;
    }
```

Comment: can you add here css ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in css using the media property for mobile width:

```
@media all and (max-width:767px){
    .row{
        position: relative;
        padding-top:30px;//the height of your arrows
    }
    .row .col-md-1{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }
    .row .col-md-1:first-child{
        left:0;
    }
    .row .col-md-1:last-child{
        right:0;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can stop to use bootstrap float left and start the use of display:flex. You can use order property to prepend the last child in the second place

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also add a hidden col next button that will show in mobile.

```
<div class="col-md-1"><!-- your current previous button -->
   <form>
    <input type="button" class="default_previous sprite" alt="Submit">
   </form>
</div><!-- your current previous button -->
<div class="col-md-1 hideondesktop"><!-- Added Next button -->
  <form>
   <input type="button" class="default-next sprite" alt="Submit">
  </form>
</div><!-- Added Next button -->
...other cols
...other cols
...other cols
<div class="col-md-1 hideonmobile"><!-- editedNext button -->
 <form>
  <input type="button" class="default-next sprite" alt="Submit">
 </form>
</div><!-- edited Next button -->
```

CSS

```
.hideondesktop{
  display:none;
}
    @media all and (max-width:767px){
     .hideondesktop{
       display:block;
     }
     .hideonmobile{
      display:none;
     }
    }
```

Hope this Help.